# Auth0: execute actions after successfull login

Tags: angular, auth0

I'm using [Auth0 Angualar library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular)'s `loginWithRedirect`  in an Angular application.
And I want to execute some actions just after successfull login (show greeting [snackBar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview), do checks by calling web services etc).
In the same time I need that after successfull loging a user will see a main app's page.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use the redirectUri option to send the user to a route that will execute whatever that is you want to execute.

Comment: thanks for the option.
I've clarified the question.
Do you know other options without `redirectUri`?

Comment: No, and I don't think there is. A part of oauth2 is to redirect the user from your single page app to their and back to yours, so you lose all execution context anyway.